# How to update (Not Create) the existing Route53 Recordset with CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I am creating the new health-check with `CFT` that I have to associate with the existing `Route53 Recordsets`. But Instead of updating existing new one, it is trying to create new one and failing with the error saying That `Recordset` already exits.

Error:

> **[Tried to create resource record set [name='partnership-weblogic-api-it-2-us-east-1.aws-card-pcat1.', type='A', set-identifier='local'] but it already exists]**

Comment: How did you update your CF you should update it as a "change set" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets-view.html not creating a new one